# Same color appears differently on various views

Tags: java, android, colors

When I use the same color on two different Views, I get different colors on each one of them...

One is defind directly in XML, and the color of the other View will be set via Java;

The XML is as the following:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#482F8B83"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_title_bar">


.
.
.



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The other, which is used in a recyclerView, looks like below ( where `R.color.all` is defined exactly equal to `#482F8B83` (which is also used, in the XML, above)):

```
viewHolder.listItemBackground.setBackgroundColor(bgColor4listItem.equals("all")?R.color.all:bgColor4listItem.equals("search")?R.color.search:R.color.top);
```

I need to get the exact same colors, but I don't!  what could be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a color `int` into `setBackgroundColor()`. Currently, you are using the resource ids of various colors. You can obtain a color `int` from a given color resource id as follows:

```
Context ctx = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();
int colorAll = ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.all);
```

Comment: So what should I do about the XML. should I Handle it just programatically?

Comment: @elyarabad - If you use `android:background="@color/all"` in your xml file and use the *colorAll* `int` like in my answer if you want to set the color programmatically,  the two colors should look the same